# Change WinForm Textbox Cursor-Color

Tags: c#, textbox, cursor

Is there a way to change the Blinking-Color of the Cursor in a selected Textbox?
On a Textbox with Background-Color in grey, the Blinking-Cursor is difficult to see...

I have currently changed the Textbox.Cursor from Ressources .cur
Image-File, but on select, the Cursor Changed in Textfield.

[image]